# Can someone explain the power supply scheme for STM32F103

Tags: power-supply, stm32

Sorry for the dumb question, I'm trying to design a board with an STM32 microcontroller and I'm confused by the power supply scheme in the datasheet. I've attached both a screenshot of the diagram and what I have so far. Can anyone explain what the circuitry should look like? Thanks.[image: What I currently have]

[image: Power supply scheme from datasheet]

Comment: What exactly confuses you? The first schematic is fine, though you may want to put an LC filter in from of VDDA at least to decouple it from the noisy digital power source. Also, you can just look up the blue pill schematic.

Comment: If you want to use the backup circuitry when the source for VDD is off (for example to keep the real time clock running), you should connect a 1.8-3.6V battery to VBAT. That’s the only real difference you might need from the first schematic. It’s also missing the recommended 100 nF decoupling cap for VDDA.

Comment: Have you read the manufacturer's application note AN2586 which explains how to get started with hardware developement, which includes an explanation for the power supply scheme?

Comment: Take a look at your pin numbers for VCC and VSS.  Thick traces from pins to cap the vias.  Or what Justme wrote.